# React Redux replace entire object in an array

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am learning Redux and I have a doubt about updating the state of an object.

Assuming I have the following initial state - an array with one objects, that is happening having filtered the object from a list.

```
export const initialState = {
    posts: []
};
```

and I want to update the title and the body of the post. The new object comes from an API response with the updated name.

I have created this reducer

```
export const postReducers = (state = initialState.posts, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case type.EDIT_POST:
            const {postEdit} = action;
            console.log('EDIT_POST STATE FROM REDUCER', postEdit);
            return [...postEdit];

        case type.DELETE_POST:
            const {postId} = action;
            console.log('DELETE_POST FROM REDUCER', postId);
            return [...state.filter(p => p.id !== postId)];

        default:
            return state
    }
};
```

When the post is updated it is then used in a map, so I need an array.

```
{
                    posts.map(post => (
                        <PostsList key={post.id}
                                   voteUp={() => this.onVote(post.id, 'upVote')}
                                   voteDown={() => this.onVote(post.id, 'downVote')}
                                   postId={post.id}
                                   postVoteScore={post.voteScore}
                                   postTitle={post.title}
                                   commentsCount={post.commentCount}
                                   postTimestamp={new Date(post.timestamp).toDateString()}
                        />))
                }
```

The this.props.postEdit sends the payload used in PUT method.

```
this.props.postEdit(savedPost.id, {title: postTitle, body: postTextArea}
```

It works as I am replacing the entire state of the object item which is a portion of my state, but is it the correct way to update an object? or Should I only update the property name? If so how should I access the property?

Consider that there is only one object so I don’t see the point in implementing a map for it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: please put real code, what is "enter code here"? So that is easier to meaningfully try to help. Any way you can try:       return {
        ...state,
        updatedVariable: newvalue, 
      };     //this way you repeat the state and only changes new value

Comment: If there is only ever one object, then don't store it in an array. Your `editPost` reducer for example would return `return {...state, post: postEdit};`

Comment: If i return an object the initial state posts: [] becomes an object and the map 'posts.map(post =>' breaks. This is the mapStateToProps from which I take the state - 'const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    categories: state.loadCategories,
    posts: state.postReducers
});
' and this is my combine reducer - export default combineReducers({
    loadCategories,
    postReducers,
    commentsReducers
}) - they are all arrays